# How to answer "ça a été ?" ?

Tags: questions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, langage-informel

The waiters would often ask "ça a été ?" after taking a dish. I sometimes lose my concentration and can't come up with anything more than a "oui oui" or "oui c'etait bien" although I know these are not the usual or appropriate answers.

What is the common answer that would mean that everything was ok? Without actually having to comment the food.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some suggestions but of course there may be plenty of other possibilities:

**Very usual** (at the restaurant, for example):

> C'était très bon, merci.
>   Tout s'est bien passé, merci.

**Common, but more familiar**:

> Je me suis régalé !
>   Un vrai festin !

If it was really a great meal and you want to show it, you can add *Mes compliments au chef*, or *Je reviendrais avec grand plaisir* after one of those expressions.

Comment: Tout s'est bien passé pour avoir bien bouffer?? Et puis je n'ai jamais dit à un garçon "je me suis régalé".

Comment: Moi j'avais entendu le "je me suis régalé" mais venant plutot des personnes plus âgées ou dans des situations ou la personne était vraiment impressionnée par le plat

Comment: On peut dire: un vrai régale. Pour les personnes âgées? Je ne pense  pas. Plutôt des gens avec un bon niveau, enfin...des gens "classe".

Comment: @Lambie « Un vrai régal » (sans e). On peut aussi très bien répondre « on s'est régalé, merci ! ».

Comment: Je suis en revanche d'accord pour trouver  « Tout s'est bien passé, merci. » inadéquat pour un plat dans un restaurant.